# I would like to light a very tiny light (led?) using RF

Tags: led, rf

I would like to light something very tiny like these hobbylinc.com/model_railroad_light_bulbs without running wires for my wife's dollhouses.  I was thinking RF to power them.  The houses are VERY small - 3 inches or so ( http://victorian-dollhouses.com/scale.html ).

Technically I have a BSEE but frankly I am more of a Comp Sci Guy.

Comment: Batteries could run them for quite a long time, but i look forward to suggestions of tesla coils ;)

Comment: Don't know about Tesla coils, but it is possible to light LEDs using electromagnetic induction. However, given that you have no experience in EE and, probably, don't have an appropriate equipment, this will take you months. I say go for batteries

Comment: @RobStarling Tesla coils (in a mild way) is the way. Put a single turn coil around the house/trainset, feed it with a few hundred kHz, make sure it is parallel resonant with a tuning capacitor and make little receiver coils for each LED, also tuned and with a reverse protection diode across the LED and a series capacitor. Should work!!

Comment: What do you mean "Without running wires"?

Comment: I have a suspicion that the "antenna" to collect enough RF power at plausibly safe field levels and affordable frequencies is going to be big enough in relation to the dollhouse that you might as well just go with wiring and simplify things drastically.  Consider copper foil under the wallpaper, or extremely fine magnet wire in the corners.

Answer (score 1):

You could use phosphorescent paint. The new [rare earth based stuff](https://www.unitednuclear.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=28_45) (not radioactive, honest) is really bright and long lasting. They use it in New York buildings for exit markings now.

No on/off switch, though..

Answer (score 0):

I used SMD 8mm reel strips on a std12Vdc wall adapter on my grandkids doll house, which are stock buys on Ebay. Otherwise using a decent rechargeable pack and LED in a suitable array to match the battery voltage can work. Getting familar with std LED and battery voltages is required then using Ohm's law to limit current for small excess voltage and hand wiring with magnet wire is useful.

I had the pleasure of working with Keith Billings at Hammond as a supplier during mid 80's and he sent me his book 1st Edition. I have found no better book on SMPS than his ,and owe everthing I know on this subject to him. He was and still is the Best in my mind on power conversion details and his results proved it. . Sorry to hear he's gone.

Comment: The 8mm smd strips are more commonly called **3528 led smd strips**. The leds themselves are roughly 3.5 x 2.8 mm. You can go smaller with 1206 or 0805 leds (or smaller). Since these are 1/144th scale, the size difference might matter.